# How to implement Landmarks in Network Analyst of ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: routing, network-analyst, arcgis-10.1

I have been trying to implement the landmark functionality into route solving in Network Analyst using ArcGIS 10.1. I have added a point class as turn landmarks (as well as playing around with confirmation landmarks as well), verified they have a valid name field, and adjusted the tolerance, yet the landmarks are not showing up in the directions. Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if you want the landmarks to be shown in the directions, you must use the geoprocessing tool found in Arc Toolbox>Network Analyst Tools>Analysis>Directions and set the style to NA Campus. The output directions will have the landmarks included. However now I am tweaking things to see if I can get it not to repeat the same landmark in each segment 4 times.